# JPA : Parallel Thread : Inserting same record : SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException

Tags: jpa, parallel-processing

Using JPARepository, we are trying to persist department and student details if not already exists. It works fine in single threaded environment.

But, it's failing with multiple threads.

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry 'DEP12' for key 'departmentId'
```

**Code Snippet :**

```
@Transactional
public void persistDetails(String departmentName, String studentName)
{
        Department dep= departmentRepository.findByDepartmentName(departmentName);
        if (dep== null) {
            dep= createDepartmentObject(departmentName);
            departmentRepository.save(dep);
        }

        ... 
}
```

How to achieve this in multi-threaded environment. We don't have to fail, instead use existing record and perform other operations.

Also, tried to catch exception and make select query inside it. But, in that case it fetches from cache object, not from DB.

**Catching Exception : Code Snippet :**

```
@Transactional
    public void persistDetails(String departmentName, String studentName)
    {
             Department dep= departmentRepository.findByDepartmentName(departmentName);

            try{                 
              if (dep== null) {
                dep= createDepartmentObject(departmentName);
                departmentRepository.save(dep);
              }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                 dep= departmentRepository.findByDepartmentName(departmentName);
            }
            ... 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement your `departmentRepository.save` in such way that it uses saveOrUpdate (if you are using Hibernate directly) or merge (if you are using JPA API).

Comment: JPA internally does this automatically :

  '@Transactional
    public <S extends T> S save(S entity) {
        if (this.entityInformation.isNew(entity)) {
            this.em.persist(entity);
            return entity;
        } else {
            return this.em.merge(entity);
        }
    }'

Answer (score 0):

You are catching exception on a wrong place. The kind of catch you show here should be done outside of the transaction. Only then you can be sure you have consistent entities in the session.

Comment: My requirement is : INSERT record if not exists, ELSE select same record from DB and perform other DB operations